# Error while passing Datetime as a parameter to a stored procedure with PyODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I need to execute a stored procedure from Python. I am using pyodbc to do that. The stored procedure requires a datetime parameter to be passed.

I am using the below code:

```
cursor.execute('exec [Data].[GetData]?',datetime.datetime.now())
```

I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (257) (SQLExecDirectW)')

What should I do ?

Comment: *"The SP requires a datetime parameter to be passed"* - The error message suggests otherwise. It appears to be expecting a bigint value. Check the documentation for the stored procedure to verify what the parameter value really should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

cursor.execute('exec [Data].[GetData]?',datetime.now())
```

had the same error check your import